# mongoose nested arrays schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a schema for the following array:

```
const data = [ [ { name: 'AKA_A2',
      path: '/',
      expires: 1510762544.752427,
      size: 7 },
    { name: 'userInfo',
      path: '/',
      expires: 0,
      size: 82 },
    { name: 'userInfo',
      path: '/',
      expires: 0,
      size: 82 } ] ]
```

This is the `Schema` that I've created:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const CookieSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    path: String,
    expires: String,
    size: String
  }
)

const RunSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    reports: {
      cookieSummary: [CookieSchema]
    }
  }
)

export default mongoose.model('Run', RunSchema);
```

Then when I'm trying to update a document from this schema I get a `null` response and the document is not updated.

This is my code:

```
Run.findOneAndUpdate({_id: runId}, {$set: {'reports.cookieSummary': data}}, (err, doc) => {
  console.log(doc);
});
```

My document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a0c5e86d4b737549e88d8cf"
    },
    "reports": {},
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: data should be array of objects [{},{},{}] , Currently it's array of array [ [ {},{}] ].

Comment: How should I change my schema to work with that format?

Comment: Wrong question. *"How should I change my data to be the correct format"*. There is little point in persisting a problem. Your data is wrong. You don't *"make a bent spanner to adjust a crooked wheel"* you just "fix the wheel" so the job is done correctly the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Change your schema to

```
const RunSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
     reports: {
        cookieSummary: [[CookieSchema]]
     }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

// In Previous Answer is not be cleared for your answer. You don't need to create two Schemas

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const RunSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    reports: {
            cookieSummary: {
                  name: String,
                  path: String,
                  expires: String,
                  size: String
             }
        }
})

export default mongoose.model('Run', RunSchema);
```